# Quarkus: How to make request @HeaderParam key as Mandatory Key

Tags: rest, quarkus

How to make the **employeeId** and **employeeName** both HeaderParam keys as Mandatory in Quarkus

```
    @POST
    @Path("/employee")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response SaveEmployeeDetails(@RequestBody Employee employeeObj, @HeaderParam("empId") BigInteger eemployeeId, @HeaderParam("empName") String employeeName) throws Exception {
        //Service Layer Code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JAX-RS specification does not provide a way to do this, your best best is to the `quarkus-hibernate-validator` extension and add the `@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation to each parameter that needs to not be null.